# Flutter test that no state is yielded from bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a case when some condition is met, then the bloc is not yielding a state at all (ignoring all events). How can I test that no state is yielded when a new event is added to bloc ?

I'm using **flutter_bloc: ^3.1.0** and **bloc_test: ^3.1.0**

```
      'test ignore all event after AlarmEvent()',
      () async {
        bloc.add(AlarmEvent());
        bloc.add(GetRandomPostEvent());

        await emitsExactly(
          bloc,
          [
            SplashScreenLoadingState(),
            ShowAlarmState(),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

As the feature is not implemented yet I'm expecting the test to fail but actually is runs successfully. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a test specifically for that condition that nothing should be emitted, and subscribe to your bloc, then call `fail()` in the subscription if the block emits, so you know they only way the test succeeded is if `fail()` wasn't called. This should be a synchronous call as well.

Something like:

```dart
var subscription = myBlocStream.listen((_) { 
  fail('Should not emit'); 
}); 
myBloc.doSomething();
subscription.cancel();
```